# Array not working on IE

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would appreciate your help with this code, it works in Google Chrome and Firefox but on IE 11 when I load the page the console show me this error message:

> SCRIPT5009: 'codigointerior' is undefined.

It is the way that im coding? Or just a IE compatibility issue?

```
idsbusqueda = new Array (codigointerior, nodeserie, fechaingreso, ubicacion, 
lugar, tipo, marca, modelo, direccion, dueño, zona, poste, color, 
descripcion);
for (var i = 0; i < idsbusqueda.length; i++) 
{
    idsbusqueda[i] = document.getElementById(idsbusqueda[i]);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If those are strings they need to be wrapped in quotes. As is you are telling it to make an array containing the value of the variable `codigointerior` which is undefined

Comment: Where's the rest of your code? Where `codigoInterior` is defined?

Comment: Not to make this weird, but the above code gives the same error in Firefox (or an other browser).

Comment: Ooh I see, thanks for your help, I wanted Store javascripst variables into array and assign DOM elements id's with the same name. I figured out that getElementById() Method require a type string as argument, and I was passing a Variable, somehow Firefox and Chrome work with my code.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's array of DOM element id's. If so, quotes needed around name of each id

```
var idsbusqueda = new Array ('codigointerior', 'nodeserie', 'fechaingreso',         'ubicacion', 
'lugar', 'tipo', 'marca', 'modelo', 'direccion', 'dueño', 'zona', 'poste', 'color', 
'descripcion');
for (var i = 0; i < idsbusqueda.length; i++) 
{
    idsbusqueda[i] = document.getElementById(idsbusqueda[i]);
}
```

Comment: That kind of looks like their intention but they may very well be assigning those variables too. We cant tell without more information.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. The error was in this part:

```
idsbusqueda[i] = document.getElementById(idsbusqueda[i]);
```

The getElementById method needs a String as argument, somehow with Firefox and Chrome works, but not IE.

```
idsbusqueda[i] = document.getElementById(String(idsbusqueda[i]));
```